# Catch "command not found" from shell script

Tags: shell-script, command-not-found

I have a shell script

```
echo "Type your command"
read command
echo "You typed $command"
$command
```

so it's simple it runs a command.My question is if the input is wrong suppose `lw` the terminal says `command not found` so how can I retrieve this information to my shell script and print to terminal `Try again wrong command`. Do I have to redirect the output of the command to a certain file and read or is there any kind of trap signal which is passed to my script.Which is your advice on how to do that it in the most efficient way.

Comment: Depending on things you may start by something like changing `$command` for `$command 2>&1 | grep ": command not found"`

Comment: @uprego : this will have a side effect of no longer displaying the normal output of 'command', and any error messages as well, as it only keeps lines containing ": commant not found" and no others.

Comment: @OlivierDulac you are incorrectly assuming that the questioner is wanting to run a command that produces standard output or error.

Comment: @uprego: ?? I think *you* are incorrectly assuming he doesn't want to see any output apart from 'command not found' ...

Comment: @OlivierDulac I'm the one no making assumptions. If that solution does not work for him, he is invited to build up a more advanced solution using combinations of the `type`, which is often a shell builtin; and `file`, which is often a /usr/bin/ program.

Comment: Chill out I didn't state whether I wanted to show the command or not the following answer works for me.@uprego I made a script with your command it prints always `command not found`,I am new to this so please excuse me if I make some obvious mistakes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a command is not found, the exit status is 127. You could use that to determine that the command was not found:

```
until
  printf "Enter a command: "
  read command
  "$command"
  [ "$?" -ne 127 ]
do
  echo Try again
done
```

While commands generally don't return a 127 exit status (for the very case that it would conflict with that standard special value used by shells), there are some cases where a command may genuinely return a 127 exit status: a script whose last command cannot be found.

`bash` and `zsh` have a special `command_not_found_handler` function (there's a typo in `bash`'s as it's called `command_not_found_handle` there), which when defined is executed when a command is not found. But it is executed in a subshell context, and it may also be executed upon commands not found while executing a function.

You could be tempted to check for the command existence beforehand using `type` or `command -v`, but beware that:

```
"$commands"
```

is parsed as a simple commands and aliases are not expanded, while `type` or `command` would return true for aliases and shell keywords as well.

For instance, with `command=for`, `type -- "$command"` would return true, but `"$command"` would (most-probably) return a *command not found* error.

`which` may fail for plenty of other reasons.

Ideally, you'd like something that returns true if the command exists as either a function, a shell builtin or an external command.

`hash` would meet those criteria at least for `ash` and `bash` (not `yash` nor `ksh` nor `zsh`). So, this would work in `bash` or `ash`:

```
while
  printf "Enter a command: "
  read command
do
  if hash -- "$command" 2> /dev/null; then
    "$command"
    break
  fi
  echo Try again
done
```

One problem with that is that `hash` returns true also for a directory (for a path to a directory including a `/`). While if you try to execute it, while it won't return a *command not found* error, it will return a `Is a directory` or `Permission Denied` error. If you want to cover for it, you could do:

```
while
  printf "Enter a command: "
  read command
do
  if hash -- "$command" 2> /dev/null &&
     { [ "${command#*/}" != "$command" ] || [ ! -d "$command" ];}
  then
    "$command"
    break
  fi
  echo Try again
done
```

Answer (score 4):

- `trap` is only for signals, which are defined in `signal(7)`. Not finding a command is simply a failure in the `exec` family of functions, which'll return `-1`, not send a signal.
- A better way to catch non-existent commands would be to do something like this.

  ```
  if ! type "$command" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      echo "Try again, wrong command" 1>&2 # should output to stderr, not stdout
  else
      "$command"
  fi
  ```

Comment: I'd also encourage you to use the `type <cmd>` and/or `command -v <cmd>` commands instead of `which`. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: Some shells like ksh, zsh and bash can trap on the special ERR non-signal. Not quoting your variables doesn't make sense here. Note all shell commands are executed by exec functions.

Comment: Note that with `bash`, that would not say that `-aaaa` for instance is a _wrong command_. `type -- "$command"` in POSIX shells would be the correct syntax, but beware that `ash`, even recent versions is not POSIX (well Unix since `type` is optional in POSIX) in that regard. You may want to use `command -v instead` (or `hash`, see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way that uses Stéphane Chazelas's code but with `type`, and overcomes `type`'s limitations...

```
function isCommand () {
  #
  local _arg=" $(type -t "$1") "
  local _executables=' file alias keyword function builtin '
  #
  [[ "${_executables#*$_arg}" != "$_executables" ]]  && return 0
  ### if $_arg is NOT in $_executables, the two strings will be identical
  #
  return 1
}

while
  printf "Enter a command: "
  read command
do
  isCommand "$command"  && { "$command"; break; }
  #
  echo Try again
done
```

#### Notes

- In isCommand()...

  - ... the variables are padded to avoid partial matches.
  - ... `type` returns "file" for any file with the execution bit set. This is the way we detect external commands.
  - ... this test for inclusion in a string is one of the most non-intuitive I know of. But it's fast and uses no external commands so I use it and wrap a more intuitive function around it. [There are a number of other ways to do this as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/string-contains-in-bash)
- `isCommand "$command"  && { "$command"; break; }`
  This uses a command list for if-then execution logic. (see [bash manpage under Shell Grammer, Lists](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash))

  - **Advantages**

    - ... faster execution than the normal `if[[...]]` construct
    - ... avoids complicated (and error-prone) multi-test logic
    - ... similar to OOP `try/catch` exception handling
  - **Caveat**

    - ... In the "then" part following the `&&` or `||`, multiple commands must be enclosed in braces and the last command and its arguments must be terminated with a semicolon `;` as in `{ cmd1 args; cmd2 args; }`.